# I'm looking for some specific events in the Windows Event Log, how can I look for them using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, event-log

The security patches released by Microsoft a few days ago can cause some Bluetooth devices to stop working. The [release notes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4507623/some-bluetooth-devices-may-fail-to-pair-or-connect-after-applying-june) explain how to check whether we will be affected: we have to check the event log, and if we find certain events, then we are affected.

These are the things to look for:

> Event Log: System
>   Event Source: BTHUSB or BTHMINI
>   Event ID: 22
>   Name: BTHPORT_DEBUG_LINK_KEY_NOT_ALLOWED
>   Level: Error
>   Event Message Text: Your Bluetooth device attempted to establish a debug connection.  The Windows Bluetooth stack does not allow debug connection while it is not in the debug mode.

I'm not very familiar with the Windows Event Viewer, and right now it isn't even working, due to [another bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4508640/event-viewer-may-close-or-you-may-receive-an-error-when-using-custom-v) (yay!).

So I'm trying to write a Powershell script, but I'm having a lot of trouble. First I tried using `Get-EventLog`, but I read it's outdated, and I should use `Get-WinEvent`. Either way, I'm stuck, because I expect to find some options to filter the output based on the criteria in the release notes, but I can't find the right arguments. What I've come up with is ([according to the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-get-winevent-queries-with-filterhashtable?view=powershell-6#filtering-by-level), 'Error' corresponds to level 2):

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
    Logname='System'
    ProviderName='BTHUSB','BTHMINI'
    Id=22
    Level=2
}
```

which gives an ugly error, whereas by changing the values of `Id` and `Level` it works, so I think my syntax is fine, and all of this probably means I won't be affected. Great.

Still, I don't understand how I could filter precisely for the name and message text.
Can anyone tell me how to map them to some options in the filter? For example, I've already found that "Event Log" is mapped to "Logname", and "Event Source" to "ProviderName". What do I have to use for Name and Message Text?

Comment: @Biswapriyo No. The only thing I have that might be somehow related is Visual Studio 2017, but that's it.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Yes, I do! Under bin I have several folders, that is: 10.0.14393.0, 10.0.15063.0, 10.0.16299.0, 10.0.17134.0, 10.0.17763.0, arm, arm64, x64, x86. Inside the 10.0.xyz folders I have both x86 and x64, and in most cases also arm, arm64 and XamlCompiler. But before you waste too much time on this, let me say that if this could lead to an alternative solution it would be great, but what I'm looking for is a way to map those "fields" to the corresponding arguments in Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You might find Nirsoft's [FullEventLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html) more convenient than PowerShell, particularly because [Windows 10 v. 1903 crashes the Event Log Viewer](https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-latest-patches-crash-event-viewer-but-microsoft-has-temporary-fix/). Though MS has released a [partial fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4508640/event-viewer-may-close-or-you-may-receive-an-error-when-using-custom-v), The free Nirsoft tool also offers capabilities in addition to those of the MS log viewer, such as searching.